# Nesting ViewFlippers

Tags: android, view

I want to nest several viewflippers. is this possible?

I have not been successful thus far.   My first tier flips as required but when I flip to the first nested viewflipper its contents appear blank and I can't "flip" it

my views are

```
V1
V2
V3 -> H1 , H2, H3
```

When I flip to V3 vertically, H1 does not appear. Where as H is my Horizontal flipper group.

Comment: I don't know much about ViewFlippers so can't help you, but generally it's a good idea to show your XML files so people can look more closely at what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Dropping in a view node after and using some explicit view dimension allowed the next fliper tiers to be visible.

Neil